# How to have two different stroke type using Paint class?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

The image (white one) is actually how I want to build that blue container.

So, How can I get two different stroke type (bottom: Dash, other: solid).

Using paint like this

```dart
Paint paint = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 10.0
      ..strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.miter
      ..color = Colors.black;
```

**What I've got**

[image: What I got.]

**What I want**

[image: What I want.]

**Full Code**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 
class UpperCustomClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path _path = Path();
 
    double radius = 44.0, w = size.width, h = size.height;
 
    _path.moveTo(radius, 0); // 1
    _path.lineTo(w - radius, 0); // 2
    _path.arcToPoint(Offset(w, radius), radius: Radius.circular(radius)); //3
    _path.lineTo(w, h - radius); // 4
    _path.arcToPoint(Offset(w - radius, h), // 5
        radius: Radius.circular(radius),
        clockwise: false);
    _path.lineTo(radius, h); // 6
    _path.arcToPoint(Offset(0, h - radius), //7
        radius: Radius.circular(radius),
        clockwise: false);
    _path.lineTo(0, radius); // 8
 
    _path.arcToPoint(Offset(radius, 0), radius: Radius.circular(radius)); // 9
 
    _path.close();
    return _path;
  }
 
  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
 
class UpperCustomPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Path _path = Path();
 
    double radius = 44.0, w = size.width, h = size.height;
 
    _path.moveTo(radius, 0); // 1
    _path.lineTo(w - radius, 0); // 2
    _path.arcToPoint(Offset(w, radius), radius: Radius.circular(radius)); //3
    _path.lineTo(w, h - radius); // 4
    _path.arcToPoint(Offset(w - radius, h), // 5
        radius: Radius.circular(radius),
        clockwise: false);
    _path.lineTo(radius, h); // 6
    _path.arcToPoint(Offset(0, h - radius), //7
        radius: Radius.circular(radius),
        clockwise: false);
    _path.lineTo(0, radius); // 8
 
    _path.arcToPoint(Offset(radius, 0), radius: Radius.circular(radius)); // 9
 
    _path.close();
 
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 10.0
      ..strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.miter
      ..color = Colors.black;
 
    canvas.drawPath(_path, paint);
  }
 
  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

Comment: you cannot have two different `Paint` styles: you need two different `Path`s - each one drawn with different `Paint`

Comment: and btw you dont need a clipper + painter: instead extend `ShapeBorder` class

Comment: @pskink I noted that.